# vue This dependency was not found:Error from chokidar (C:\): Error: EBUSY: resource busy or locked, lstat 'C:\hiberfil.sys'

Tags: vue.js, validation, npm, vuex

I'm using vue , after npm run serve .
I got this error .
[image]

Any Idea , how can I fix it ?

Comment: Did you run "npm i" and then "npm audit fix" before running "npm run serve" ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your project is referencing a file/project that doesn't exist. Check for all your import "from" links and URLs.

Answer (score -3):

When you initialize the empty project for the first time do not forget to run:

```
npm i
```

Then:

```
npm audit fix
```

And at the end you should run the app by calling:

```
npm run serve
```

Comment: answer is not related to the question

Comment: @StéphaneGerber the answer is the exact solution of the problem.